# How mapping the fields?

Tags: apex, servicenow

I'm trying to create salesforce case as servivenoe incident but i'm facing problem at mapping

No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

Hi This my apex class and trigger 'm going to create an incident in serviceNow from salesforce but the below code execution i'm getting some errors anyone guide me to resolve them and creating an incident in serviceNow

This is my apex class:

```
public class SericeNow{

public static void servicenowPost(Case incidentCase){  

 Http http = new Http();
 HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();
 HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

 String username = 'admin';
 String password = '$Test12345';

  Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
  String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
  req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

  req.setEndpoint('https://dev23577.service-now.com/');
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  //how map the fields here case fields with incident fields

  }
}
```

Thanks,
Sushanth

Comment: based on that i modified the code but after creating the case in salesforce the incident isn't created in serviceNow please help me to resolve

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I understand that you wrote code according to the answer from your last question and its not working. Any error you are getting? Why are you asking for how to map fields again?